# Passing javascript argument using bind()

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MRN Number" ItemStyle-Width="6%">
     <ItemTemplate>

          <asp:Label ID="lblMRNNumber" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("MRNNumber") %>'
               onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this,' test');"></asp:Label>

      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

My javascript function

```
 tooltip.pop(this,'test')
```

working fine when mouse hover.
But I want like below.(Which means instead of 'test' , need to pass the MRNNumber

```
tooltip.pop(this,'<%#Bind("MRNNumber") %>')
```

how to do this... is it possible.

Comment: Please post your html using browser's "view source"

Comment: the page has large so i put part of it, <td style="width:6%;">
                                                    <div class="textEllipsis">
                                                        <span id="ctl15_gvIndentSearch_ctl03_lblMRNNumber" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this,Eval(&#39;MRNNumber&#39;));"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>

Comment: What does `#Bind(...)` do?

Comment: Flix Kling, Bind is an example, I want to pass the MRNNumber value to tooltip.pop function's one of the argument.

Comment: I have a reference [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793921/how-to-properly-pass-eval-to-javascript-function) onmouseover='<%# String.Format("tooltip.pop(this,(\"{0}\")", Eval("MRNNumber"))%>' but it wont work I got error from IE status bar as Expected ')', Can any one modify for my requirement. Thanks.

Comment: are you using C# or VB?

Comment: Well, you said in the title *"Passing javascript argument using bind()"*, so I assumed that's the "bind" you are talking about and it's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation within the onmouseover attribute.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MRN Number" ItemStyle-Width="6%">
 <ItemTemplate>

      <asp:Label ID="lblMRNNumber" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("MRNNumber") %>'
         onmouseover='<%= "tooltip.pop(this,'" & Eval("MRNNumber") & "');" %>'></asp:Label>

  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I haven't tried that with `onmouseover`, though.  traditional server control properties can be set this way.

Comment: I just added a space between the last double quote and the percent sign.  See if that helps.

Comment: Error , Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs